# TranscoderException when converting svg to image using Batik

Tags: java, svg, batik

I am trying to convert `svg` content into a `pdf` or `png` file. I am using Batik to do this. My code is as follows:

```
Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
TranscoderOutput transcoderOutput = new TranscoderOutput(new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFilePath + "\\" + outputFileName + ".pdf")));
transcoder.transcode(transcoderInput, transcoderOutput);
```

However, I get the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
Enclosed Exception:
Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:226)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(ImageTranscoder.java:92)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
    at com.we.poc.svgConverterdemo.conv.POC.main(POC.java:35)
Caused by: org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext.getReferencedNode(BridgeContext.java:788)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext.getReferencedElement(BridgeContext.java:804)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertURIPaint(PaintServer.java:365)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertPaint(PaintServer.java:273)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertFillPaint(PaintServer.java:242)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertFillAndStroke(PaintServer.java:160)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGShapeElementBridge.createShapePainter(SVGShapeElementBridge.java:117)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGDecoratedShapeElementBridge.createFillStrokePainter(SVGDecoratedShapeElementBridge.java:58)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGDecoratedShapeElementBridge.createShapePainter(SVGDecoratedShapeElementBridge.java:84)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGShapeElementBridge.buildGraphicsNode(SVGShapeElementBridge.java:91)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:219)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:219)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:219)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:219)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:219)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:219)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:141)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createSVGImageNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:697)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createImageGraphicsNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:296)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.buildImageGraphicsNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:179)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:121)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:213)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:219)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:208)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: What content are you using as input?

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace, it looks like some fill definition references an external file. Look at **that** file closely and make sure it is [valid XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-prolog-dtd):

> at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142)
> ... Caused by:
> org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> at org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext.getReferencedNode(BridgeContext.java:788)
> at org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext.getReferencedElement(BridgeContext.java:804)
> at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertURIPaint(PaintServer.java:365)
> at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertPaint(PaintServer.java:273)
> at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertFillPaint(PaintServer.java:242)